# Ranger file manager - Access remote server?

Tags: console, sftp, remote-access, file-management

Is is possible to access remote servers in Ranger (cli) file manager using sftp/fish/... protocols, example:

```
sftp://user@server/home/user
```

Answer (score 11):

It does not look like it would be possible using Ranger. But you can mount remote filesystem using `sshfs` and then access it as every other file on your local system:

```
mkdir /mnt/server
sshfs user@server:dir /mnt/server
cd /mnt/server
```

Comment: Thanks but sshfs is too slow. sftp is much faster for directory browsing. Hopefully this will be added in future versions. Until then I will use krusader for sharing files over remote servers

Comment: `sshfs` is using `sftp` under the hood so the only slower thing might be using `fuse` on your system creating the abstract file-system layer. I don't think it can be so bad.

Comment: Thanks for info, let me correct myself - Exploring sshfs mounted file system on Ubuntu 12.04 is slow. I suppose it cannot be mounted in Ubuntu without "fuse" layer.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The `fuse` is the `fs` thing in `sshfs`. What I proposed is universal, but not the best-performance. You can of course connect to the other server, install the ranger there and run it remotely, which will be faster.

Comment: Great suggestions, as you said I am running ranger on remote server through ssh. Ranger is ideal for that purpose! ssh + Vim + ranger + tmux = great remote control

Answer (score 1):

You can use rclone to mount many different cloud shares like sftp, webdav, s3, google drive, ... to your local filesystem.

Only for ssh I found no rclone remote system.